# Oracle SQL - Filling in columns based on previous records and leaving records with no previous data NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some columns in a table set up like this:

```
ID      IDSEQUENCENUM   DATE
1       1               20050101
1       2               
1       3               
1       4               20050505
2       1               20120303
2       2               20120404
2       3               
3       1               
3       2
3       3               20140505
...
```

What I need to do is when the Date is null is to fill it in as the previous IDSEQUENCENUM within that ID.  If there are no previous dates for that ID/IDSEQUENCENUM it is to remain null. So the above would look like this afterward:

```
ID      IDSEQUENCENUM   DATE
1       1               20050101
1       2               20050101
1       3               20050101
1       4               20050505
2       1               20120303
2       2               20120404
2       3               20120404
3       1               
3       2
3       3               20140505
...
```

There's no saying how many Null values for DATE there will be in between each record.

Thanks for the help!

(Oh and in case your curious the date is in a varchar2 format due to the way a program using this data needs to accept it)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for, following the previous answer:

```
select id, idseq, 
       case when dateval is null then last_value(dateval) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by idseq) else dateval
       end as dateval
from dates
order by id, idseq;
```

For update changes do it like this:

```
merge into dates dt2 using 
(
select id, idseq, 
       case when dateval is null then last_value(dateval) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by idseq) else dateval
       end as dateval
from dates
order by id, idseq
) dt
on (DT2.ID = dt.id and DT2.IDSEQ = dt.idseq )
when matched then
update set DT2.DATEVAL = dt.dateval
```

I hope it's helps.

Comment: The select statement works great! Thanks! However, when I try to change it to an update to actually change the rows I'm running into error 'ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here' when it gets to last_value. Can you offer any insight into this?

Comment: You can use the `MERGE` statement to update your table based on an arbitrary query. The query that gives you the new values goes to the `USING` clause.

Comment: @Florian Yes, that's correct, you can use a merge to update from a query, I will edit my answer using Florian suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The following query gets you the expected results (using a_horse_with_no_name's column and table names)

```
select 
  s1.id,
  s1.idsequencenum, 
  case
    when s1.date_col is null then max(s2.date_col)
    else s1.date_col
  end modified_date_col
from simple s1
left outer join simple s2
on s2.id = s1.id and s2.idsequencenum < s1.idsequencenum and s2.date_col is not null --and s1.date_col is null
group by 
  s1.id,
  s1.idsequencenum, 
  s1.date_col
order by
  s1.id,
  s1.idsequencenum;
```

Here's the `MERGE` statement to perform the update:

```
merge into simple s
using
(
  select 
    s1.id,
    s1.idsequencenum, 
    case
      when s1.date_col is null then max(s2.date_col)
      else s1.date_col
    end modified_date_col
  from simple s1
  left outer join simple s2
  on s2.id = s1.id and s2.idsequencenum < s1.idsequencenum and s2.date_col is not null --and s1.date_col is null
  group by 
    s1.id,
    s1.idsequencenum, 
    s1.date_col
) t
on (s.id = t.id and s.idsequencenum = t.idsequencenum)
when matched then
  update set s.date_col = t.modified_date_col;
```

**Updated** <kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ddb70/15)</kbd>

Comment: This select statement also works great , thank you! However, when I try my best to translate it into an update statement, once again I'm running into trouble just like the code below.  Except this time I'm getting an 'ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here'.  I feel pretty dumb having two great answers and not being able to work with them :( oh well at least I'm learning, right?

Comment: As Florian suggested in another comment, you can use the `MERGE` statement. Please see modified answer above.

Comment: The merge worked! (of course you all knew it would)  I wasn't familiar with this method.  What a great community here.  Thanks for the help everyone!